# Install KeePassHttp plugin for KeepassX on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, google-chrome-extensions, keepassx

I installed KeepassX on my new Mac and I want to use a plugin (KeePassHttp) to autofill logins on Chrome. The instructions tell me to place it in the program directory of KeepassX but I cannot drag it into the application file and I'm not sure how to do this with Terminal.

The Chrome plugin page shows that KeePassHttp is active but cannot detect or make a connection with KeepassX

How can I finish this plugin install?

Answer (score 6):

There's a forked alpha version of KeePassX available which has built in support for HTTP integration and works fine with ChromeIPass (and therefore likely others).

You don't need to install KeePassHttp just install the full KeePassX from https://github.com/keithbennett/keepassx/releases

Comment: Here's a better one with better instructions. http://dareneiri.github.io/Setting-Up-KeePassX-With-Autologin/

Answer (score 5):

KeePassHttp is a plugin for KeePass and not for KeePassX; KeePassX has no plugin interface and is not a front-end for KeePass.

Comment: This may not be true anymore.  See other responses.

Answer (score 2):

Look at KyPass Companion: http://www.kyuran.be/blog/2013/03/07/kypass-companion-v0-2/
It's fully compatible with KeePassHTTP and works natively on MacOSX

Comment: It has its own page now: http://www.kyuran.be/logiciels/kypass4mac/

Answer (score 1):

I also investigated KeePassHttp and it seems to only be compatible with Windows.

Further info from the plugin [author's website](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae):

> Linux and Mac users:
>   If you are using KeePass with Mono, then you're in luck.  I have tested KeePassHttp with Mono 2.6.7 and it appears to work well.  I cannot get the plgx file to work on Linux, perhaps you may have more luck, but I can get my dll files to work directly when put into the KeePass directory (possibly the Plugin directory as well, I have not tried).  You can get KeePassHttp.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.dll from https://github.com/pfn/keepasshttp/tree/master/KeePassHttp

Comment: This may not be true anymore.  See other responses.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that KeePassHttp works on Mac using the mono-based version: all you have todo is follow the instructions provided and drop the two dll files (KeePassHttp.dll and Newtonsoft.Json.dll ) inside the application directory (use "show package contents" on the context menu when you click over the application icon on Finder and then go to "Contents > MacOS" ).

But firtst, download the KeePass 2 mono version here: [keepass2.openix.be](http://keepass2.openix.be/)

and then the mono framework for Mac (the links are provided there). I used the Mono 3.2 version, which is the most recent at the time I'm writing.

Answer (score 0):

Regular Keepass over Mono has problems on Mac OS like being unable to support copy/paste functionality (which is a must for me as I use a very long master key). I suggest you try https://github.com/mstarke/MacPass which is an attempt to create an OS X port of KeePass.